# Understandability vs Performance

Tags: performance

I was having a discussion at work today about code around weather it is more important for people(especially juniors) to understand or to have high performance code.

I am all for having less efficient as long as it is easy for anyone to understand, as it code is always handed off to junior developers to support.

Comment: Would migrate this to [Programmers.SE], but it would be a duplicate many times over. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=readability+performance

Comment: It's a [false dilemma](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89620/clean-readable-code-vs-fast-hard-to-read-code-when-to-cross-the-line/89624#89624).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you should try to keep it as understandable as possible. When you hit performance issues that *must* be dealt with and the resolution that helps you achieve your performance goals is not as understandable, you must document it *very well* before handing it off to the junior devs.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the golden mean, considering who works the code, and what is the final goal of your program.

As for our company, we don't care about 'understandability' and pursue the high performance. This is easy for us, because we don't have junior developers :)

Comment: +1 for seeking the best of both worlds: you can have readable, efficient code if you make the effort. Anyway, if not possible, err on favor of code readability